# Why textarea freezes when using jQuery function append to insert text

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm trying to insert something in a text area (`#note_text`) from a drop down list (`#note_template`). User should be able to insert a number of items into the text area in between typing characters using the keyboard. Similar to selecting from a collection of emoticons to be put in the message.

When done in the followign way, the text area can receive items after typing.

```
function update1() {
    $txt = $("#note_text").val() + $("#note_template option:selected").val() ;
    $("#note_text").val($txt);
$("#note_template").val("");
}
```

But when done in the following way, the content of the text area wouldn't update after typing. Only before typing I can insert items from the drop down list.

```
function noteTempalteSelected() {
    $("#note_text").append( $("#note_template option:selected").val() );
    $("#note_template").val("");
}
```

So it seems that the use of `append` causes the text area to freeze. **Could anyone explain why ?** Thank you.

Comment: what does $("#note_text").trigger("keyup"); suppose to do here

Comment: I put a keyup handler to count and show the number of characters written in the text area. The triggering is needed to update that value.

Comment: just tested without triggering keyup, the problem remains.

Comment: I'm guessing the second method doesn't work because: you don't want to "append" inside a textarea, you want to add to the - value - of the textarea. In other words, I'd expect the same problem if you were appending to a <input type="submit" />, or any other element that doesn't actually wrap around HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I know whats going on here. For the append to work properly, the element should have an innerHTML property or html() in jquery. Textarea just like the input has a val() property. So for this to work properly you should try this:

```
 $('#note_template').on('click', 'option:selected', function(e){
   var txtArea = $('#note_text');
   txtArea.val(txtArea.val() + $(this).val());
   $(this).val(''); 
 });
```

[**[DEMO HERE][1]**](http://jsbin.com/voqax/1/edit)

Comment: not quite. I was looking for an explanation why one of code snippet worked while the other would freeze the text area.

Comment: ya, this also freezes.

Comment: Hey Alex, this one works. But I already knew that, see the first code I posted. I'm looking for the explanation, why would this work while the append freezes. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: I see your point. But how would you explain the fact that I can insert items before I type. Lets say my items from the drop down are ":)" and ":(", I can insert a few smilies before I start typing. Then I type one chracter, "a". So now I have ":) :)a". Now I cannot insert anything from the drop down anymore.

Comment: Try it in my demo example. It works there. However you can  not insert same item twice, because of $(this).val(''); If you want to be able to insert the same item twice, then you should remove this line.